# saving data of all the replication of the experiment in anylogic

Tags: replication, anylogic

Does anyone knows how can we save the data of all the replication of the experiment in Anylogic? I have 6 variables and 4 statistics that are my output results, how can I get the whole data related to these variables and statistics for every replication iteration?

Answer (score 1):

there is a code boxe in your experiment properties called "after replication". Here, you have access to your "root" (i.e. Main) and can store all model values that you like to an external data storage or the build-in dbase. Also, some useful example models that you might want to check in the example-model-library.

cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can you please name some of those examples. I need to know the codes for doing the data storage. Thank you.